# Linux audio player that can filter songs per year

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, audio-player

Sometimes I want to play only 90s songs, and sometimes only songs that have been released this year.

Is there a Linux audio player with that feature?

That can be a plugin of an existing player.
Bonus if it is an Audacious plugin, as I currently use Audacious.

Gratis, ideally open source.

Answer (score 0):

[Clementine Audio Player](https://www.clementine-player.org/) is able to do such a thing. It has got a smart playlist feature ("*Create smart playlists and dynamic playlists*", as they say on their website). For this, click on the Library button in the left tool bar. At the top of the library panel, you have got a "smart playlists" section. Right-click on it, then click on "new smart playlist" to create the playlist of your dreams. It opens a creation window where you can set all the required conditions for your songs to be in that playlist. There is also a preview of your playlist at the bottom of the window. Follow the instructions and enjoy the songs you want to enjoy listening to your smart playlists.

Clementine is available for Windows, macOS and Linux. It is free, both as in "free beer" (gratis) and as in "free software" (under GPL v3.0 license). The latest update looks old (3 years ago) but the project is still active. You can still build Clementine from source ([available on GitHub](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine)) if you want a more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

[Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/downloads.html) has the ability to filter tracks based on many date fields including "Release Year". Hence you can use this feature for playing tracks or for setting up a playlist. You can see more details on Search [here](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/searching.html#searching).

It is open source, and runs on Linux, Windows, MacOS.